# Interpreting R nnet output Multinomial Regression

Tags: r, regression, interpretation, multinomial-distribution

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me interpret my results. I am struggling to find anywhere online which it simple to follow.

I have conducted a multinomial regression. I have a dataset with an outcome variable (verdict: guilty, not guilty and not proven) and two predictor variables (complexity: standard and scientific --> called standardsci as a variable) and (timing: before and after --> called afterbef as a variable)

I have used the relevel function to select a baseline category for my outcome variables. (verdictoutputvariable)

The model: 
[image]

I then used the Z tests to get p values 
[image]

I am just unsure how to interpret these results? I am writing my dissertation and this is just one predictor variable. Any advice on how to actually interpret these would be amazing!

Comment: You've posted on this dataset quite a few times. Perhaps there's a code book for your data which you could quote from. You can't interpret categorical effects without understanding their levels.

Answer (score 1):

The `nnet:multinom` function is a special case of a log-linear model. My favorite reference for these models is Alan Agresti's "Categorical Data Analysis" 2nd ed (or higher) which should be fairly easy to find. The most important finding is that the log-linear model is a special case of logistic regression. That is exactly how `nnet` works. The model coefficients are just odds ratios for that specific response. Their values are constrained so that the fitted probabilities add to 1 across the possible multinomial response levels. The odds ratio compares the odds of a particular response level (versus any other response level) for a positive exposure group to a negative exposure group. You must exponentiate the column of "estimate" and its 95% CI to convert to the odds ratio scale.